# Invalid Firebase Path error while fetching database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase for both authentication and realtime database. My authentication code was successfully run also my enter value to database code also run, but when I am coding for fetch value in database, I am getting run time error trying to enter value at Firebase database:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process:com.xxx.xxx, PID: 22601
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database 
path: https://xxx-exxe.firebaseio.com/. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
```

My Code is :

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("https://korsa-e03ae.firebaseio.com/");

reference.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Offerride user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Offerride.class);

        if (user == null){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"User data is null!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        tvsource.setText(user.source + " , " + user.destination + " , " + user.startDate + " , " + user.startTime);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failefddd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why is it that the `ValueEventListener()` and `DataSnapshot` being used with the `com.google.firebase.database.` prefix? Does it throw an error when you remove it?

Comment: your firebase path value contain the one of the folowing  character   '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'   .so reference path do not contain these characters.You will get this eror when you are calling childs of this path

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is quite obvious you don't need to specific the `url` because app is already link to the `database` when you set up the project

just change from

`DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("https://korsae03ae.firebaseio.com/");`

to

`DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference();`

Then it should work

Comment: Thanks how do I not see this?. Had getReferencefromUrl instead of getReference

Answer (score 0):

Url of your database is in your google-services.json file.
By firebase docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data to read  data, you can do the following:

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("posts");

// Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
    System.out.println(post);
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using getReferance use, getReferanceFromUrl.
and in your case: database.getReference.child("posts");