# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

when I try to store my location's latitude and longitude on my database I get this error

```
01-02 11:54:30.820 24616-24616/? E/Zygote: no v2
01-02 11:54:30.830 24616-24616/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] 
get_category:   variable   seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
01-02 11:54:33.823 24616-24616/com.rescuex_za.rescuex
E/AndroidRuntime:    FATAL EXCEPTION: main

                                                                                  Process:
 com.rescuex_za.rescuex, 
PID: 24616
                                                                                 com.google.firebase.database.
 DatabaseException:
 Invalid Firebase Database path:
 https://rescuex-8f9c9.firebaseio.com/Users/NcZ0McVHEuRfaMv39gHbDlpjI1X2.    Firebase Database paths must not contain
   '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelv.zzqh(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.rescuex_za.rescuex.MenuActivity.addEmergencyChat(MenuActivity.java:247)
                                                                        at com.rescuex_za.rescuex.MenuActivity.access$100(MenuActivity.java:55)
                                                                        at com.rescuex_za.rescuex.MenuActivity$1.onClick(MenuActivity.java:106)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

this is my class where i send the location's latitude AND Longitude

```
   public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, 
       OnMapReadyCallback,
         ConnectionCallbacks,
         OnConnectionFailedListener  {

private static final  String TAG = "RescueX";
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;
private DatabaseReference mLocationDatabase;

ImageButton fakeCallBtn;
Button mRescue;
ImageButton notif;
ImageButton flash;
private  Double lati;
private GoogleMap mMap;
LocationManager locationManager;

private DatabaseReference mRootRef;
private String mCurrentUserId;
private String userName;
private DatabaseReference user_id;
private String mChatUser;

private String message;
private String value_lat = null;
private String value_long = null;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference mUserRef;
LocationTrack locationTrack;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mLocationDatabase = mRootRef.child("EmergencyMessages");
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCurrentUserId =  mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    user_id = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mCurrentUserId);
    mChatUser = user_id.getRef().toString();
    buildGoogleApiClient();


    mRescue = (Button)findViewById(R.id.rescue);
    mRescue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            addEmergencyMessage();
            addEmergencyChat();


        }
    });

    fakeCallBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fake_callbtn);
    fakeCallBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent fakecallIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, FakeCalling.class);
            startActivity(fakecallIntent);
        }
    });
    flash = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.flash);
    flash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent flashIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, FlashLight.class);
            startActivity(flashIntent);
        }
    });

    notif = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.notification_btn);
    notif.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, Notifications.class);
            startActivity(notificationIntent);
        }
    });

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("RescueX ");

    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {


        mUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        mUserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                userName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.e("fist","error");

        return ;

    }


    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                //get latitude
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                //get longitude
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                    String str = addressList.get(0).getCountryName() + ",";
                    str += addressList.get(0).getLocality();

                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));

                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10.2f));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }


            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                      .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                      .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                      .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                      .build();
}

private void addEmergencyChat() {


    value_lat = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()).replace(".","d");
    value_long = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()).replace(".","d");
            String current_user_ref="Emergency_Messages/"+mCurrentUserId+"/"+mChatUser;
            String chat_user_ref= "Emergency_Messages/"+mChatUser+"/"+mCurrentUserId;

            DatabaseReference chat_push_key = mRootRef.child("Emergency_Messages").child(mCurrentUserId).
                    child(mChatUser).push();

            String push_key = chat_push_key.getKey();

            Map messageMap = new HashMap();
            messageMap.put("userName", userName);
            messageMap.put("latitude",value_lat);
            messageMap.put("longitude", value_long);
            messageMap.put("from",mCurrentUserId);
            messageMap.put("seen",false);
            messageMap.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

            Map messageUserMap = new HashMap();
            messageUserMap.put(current_user_ref+ "/"+push_key,messageMap);
            messageUserMap.put(chat_user_ref+ "/"+push_key,messageMap);

            mRootRef.updateChildren(messageUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                    if(databaseError!=null){
                        Log.d("TAG",databaseError.getMessage().toString());
                    }
                }
            });

    }



private void addEmergencyMessage() {

    mRootRef.child("Emergency_Chat").child(mCurrentUserId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(mChatUser)){

                Map chatAddMap = new HashMap();
                chatAddMap.put("seen",false);
                chatAddMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

                Map chatUserMap = new HashMap();
                chatUserMap.put("Emergency_Chat/"+mCurrentUserId+"/"+mChatUser, chatAddMap);
                chatUserMap.put("Emergency_Chat/"+mChatUser+"/"+mCurrentUserId, chatAddMap);

                mRootRef.updateChildren(chatUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                        if(databaseError!= null){
                            Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "Error: "+databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if(currentUser == null){

        sendToStart();

    } else {

        mUserRef.child("online").setValue("true");

    }

}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if(currentUser != null) {

        mUserRef.child("online").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

    }

}

private void sendToStart() {

    Intent startIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, Home.class);
    startActivity(startIntent);
    finish();

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    if(item.getItemId()== R.id.log_out){
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        sendToStart();

    }



    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent notifIntent= new Intent(MenuActivity.this, Settings.class);
        startActivity(notifIntent);
    }
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.all_users){

        Intent usersIntent= new Intent(MenuActivity.this, UsersActivity.class);
        startActivity(usersIntent);

    }

    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_profile_layout) {
        Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, Profile.class);
        startActivity(searchIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_users_activity) {
        Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, UsersActivity.class);
        startActivity(searchIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_history_layout) {
        Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, History.class);
        startActivity(searchIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_help_layout) {
        Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, Help.class);
        startActivity(searchIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_feedback_layout) {
        Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, Feedback.class);
        startActivity(searchIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_signout_layout) {
        Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, SignOut.class);
        startActivity(searchIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_friends_layout) {
        Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, FriendsActivity.class);
        startActivity(searchIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, Share.class);
        startActivity(searchIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null){
        value_lat = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()).replace(".","d");
        value_long = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()).replace(".","d");

    }


}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
  Log.i(TAG,"Connection suspended");
  mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, " Connection Failed "+ connectionResult.getErrorMessage());

}

@Override
public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

}
```

}

What I want to do is read the location that is being displayed when the user open's a page containing the above code, after reading the user's location I want to store those values in my database which I will later retrieve in another class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid Firebase Path error while fetching database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466508/invalid-firebase-path-error-while-fetching-database)

Comment: Heisen-Berg how can i identifiy those duplicates?

Comment: About this line:
DatabaseReference chat_push_key = mRootRef.child("Emergency_Messages").child(mCurrentUserId).
                    child(mChatUser).push();

Can you please print out the value of "mChatUser" and "mChatUserId"? I think it may contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

Comment: okay let me check it

Comment: Your database reference contain invalid characters like '.', '#', ''$', '[', ']', Log your database reference and replace those invalid characters.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the . with * didn't really work and from what Cao Minh Vu suggested that it might have a problem the mChatUser was pointing to a null value so I sorted that out and for may latitude and longitude is used:

```
String lat = String.ValueOf(latitude.getLatitude());
String long = String.valueOf(longitude.getLongitude());
```

Thanks to everyone who commented on my Post, I wasn't going to identify the problem because there's too many lines in my code it was hard to identify which one was giving me a problem